# C++ difference between passing argument from a function call or passing argument from variable

Tags: c++, function, variables, arguments

Whats the difference between this:

```
function1(function2());
```

And this:

```
var1 = function2();
function1(var1);
```

In terms of efficiency or whatever, what is the best option?

Comment: `function1(function2());` ? As currently written the comparison makes no sense

Comment: Yea sorry i edit it

Comment: It mostly depends on what type will `var1` have, but `function1(function2());` will copy data less times :) In terms of clear code it will be probably better to keep `var1` (with better name) and pass it as reference or even const erference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++11 there is no big difference. Since move semantics were introduced the difference can be substantial. For example when a function needs to make a copy of its parameter it can have two overloads: one that actually does make a copy and another one that can move when the parameter is a temporary:

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar {};
bar b() { return {};}

struct foo {
    bar b;
    void set(const bar& in) { 
        std::cout << "copy \n";
        b = in;
    }
    void set(bar&& in){
        std::cout << "no need to copy, can move\n"; 
        b = std::move(in);
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    bar b1;
    f.set(b1);
    f.set(b());
}
```

`bar` in this example is just a lightweight class, but when it is cheap to move but expensive to copy then `f.set(b1)` is less efficient than `f.set(b())`. The caller could `f.set(std::move(b1))`, but it is more clear to call `f.set(b())` rather than having a moved from object hanging around.

---

However, already before C++11, the question you should actually ask is: Does it make sense to give a name to the result of calling `function2`? Do you need the result only to call `function1` or do you need it also elsewhere? And this can be answered independently of whether you are writing ancient C++ or whether move semantics are involved. In short: Write code to be clear and readable. Concerns about efficieny are for a later stage, when you have correct and working code that you can measure and profile.

Comment: what if set will take copy instead of const ref like this: `void set(bar in)`? :)

Comment: @Raffallo not sure if I understand what you mean. If `set` takes the parameter by copy then it does make a copy and cannot benefit from move-semantics. It really depends on what `function1` is, but without knowing that it is a valid assumption that it can either move or copy